# SQL Find MAX Values for multiple rows

Tags: sql

Data Set

```
Name    Number  Value
Alabama  254    100
Atlas    156    200
Alabama  354    300
Atlas    800    400
```

SQL Statement as to return the Max Number per Name.

desired outcome

```
Alabama  354    300
Atlas    800    400
```

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server or PostgreSQL? I've removed the multiple RDNMS tags, feel free to add back the relevant one.

Comment: What if you had `(Alabama, 400, 10)`? What would be the expected output then?

Comment: *to return the Max Number per Name.* If so why do you show `Value` column in desired output?

Comment: Add the row (Atlas, 500, 500) and also adjust the expected result - if needed.

Comment: Max Number and return all columns

Comment: if you add Alabama, 400, 10 it should return this instead of the Alabama, 354, 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SQL Statement as to return the Max Number per Name.

What you describe sounds like:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.number = (select max(t2.number) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

In most databases, this has optimal or close-to optimal performance with an index on `(name, number)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on` in `PostgreSQL`:

```
select distinct on (name) *
from table t
order by name, number desc;
```

You can use `row_number()` to general :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by number desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

If number has ties then you can use `rank()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `SQL Server` and `MySQL` you can use `MAX()` function with group by. Try like:

```
SELECT Name,MAX(Number),MAX(Value) 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Name
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/554280/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use just max function to find the maximum value
like.

```
SELECT Name,MAX(Number),MAX(Value) 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: For reference See [Formatting code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You can first Order by Number and then GROUP BY name like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
name, MAX(number) AS number, MAX(value) AS value
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I can't use MAX(value) as the value field is not necessarily the MAX that I want to select. MAX must be only the number.

Comment: But if you actually do want value then you must want any one of all, because as you said, more than one value of value isnt possible for alabama if you only want one record of alabama right?